# Unwanted characters when looping through text file

Tags: c, file, io

I have a text file containing only letters that looks like so:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

I am attempting to go through the file and save all of the characters in a string. Here is my code:

```
// Set sequence variable to sequence in file
for ( seqlength = 0; (symbol = getc(f)) != EOF;){   //seqlength is an int
                                                    //symbol is a char
                                                    //f is a file pointer 
   if ( symbol != '\n'){
      sequence[seqlength] = symbol;                 //sequence is a char[]
      seqlength++;
   }
}
```

When I print out `printf("sequence: %s length: %d\n", sequence, strlen(sequence));`
 after this loop completes, I get the `AAAABBBBCCCC` string as expected, but with a bunch of garbage characters after the last C and a `strlen` of 22 when 12 is expected.

Can anyone provide a simple fix to this to make it work?

Thanks

Edit: I would like to also add that the non alphanumeric character appears to change every time when I run the code and print it to the console. Using the GCC compiler in Code::Blocks.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever intended on **incrementing** `seqlength` in that loop. Terminating the string before the dump would be a bonus, I imagine.

Comment: Is the dump what's causing all of those garbage characters at the end?

Comment: I suggest you clear the sequence buffer to all '\0' before placing characters into it.  Then you will not need to worry about terminating the string later in the code.  Also, on some systems '\n' is a multi character item, so would fail to be recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage you see is the result of failing to terminate the string with the null character.

```
for ( seqlength = 0; (symbol = getc(f)) != EOF;){   //seqlength is an int
                                                    //symbol is a char
                                                    //f is a file pointer 
   if ( symbol != '\n'){
      sequence[seqlength] = symbol;                 //sequence is a char[]
      seqlength++;
   }
}

// Terminate string with the null character.
sequence[seqlength] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not seen this before, though it makes sense why you need to. Appreciate the answer.